# Change PHP Object Instance to a Parent

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a class base which has a property called load which is a object of the class load. The load class has a function called view that includes pages. Now I need to call,

***This is similar to CodeIgniter's $this->load->view("test.php");***

**Load Class**

```
class Load {
    public function view($page){
        //this function loads views to display
        include($page);
    }
    public function model($class){
        //loads model classes
    }
    public function library($class){
        //loads libraries
    }
}
```

**Base Class**

```
class Base {
    function __construct(){
        $this->load = new Load();
    }
}
```

**Index page**

```
$base = new Base();
$base->load->view("test1.php");
```

**this1.php**

```
echo "testing1\n";

$this->load->view("test2.php");
```

**test2.php**

```
echo "testing2";
```

**The output should be**

```
testing1
testing2
```

Comment: make your view function public `public function view($page){`

Comment: A better OOP approach would be to have a wrapper method inside the base class...

Comment: Please put some effort into the question. You haven't explained that your problem is and it's hard to figure out given that your snippet omits context.

Comment: the page is in the load class but I want to reference it from the class base

Comment: ... and your current approach is not satisfactory because... :-?

Comment: if you want to reference it from the base class you should have the `$page` in the base class?

Comment: I don't get the problem? You could extend the Load class right? http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZrgLTt

Comment: If i dont't want to extend the Load class I just want to use the functionality of the class

Comment: But the functions are private ?

Comment: From what I can tell your question is "It doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want I think is to follow a factory pattern. (At least, that's what you mean if you want the `$view` variable to actually contain an instance of the `Load` class)

Make the constructor protected, so that the only the class can create new instances, then in the base class add a static method, e.g. 'factory' which returns an instance of the desired class.

Then your code would look like

```
$view=Base::factory();
$view->view("test1.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this answer was made before any edit made to the question. Please evaluate accordingly

You need to have the functions marked as `public` to allow them to be called from outside of the defining class (this is simplified of course)

Try the following:

```
class Load{
    public function view($page){
       include($page);
    }
}

class Base{
    public $load;
    function __construct(){
        $this->load = new Load();
    }
}
```

(The uppercase class names are my own preference)

This should work, but it's not a good design from a clean OOP perspective, because the users of the `Base` class need to know how the `Load` class works. This is called "tight coupling" and should be avoided as much as possible.

I suggest to consider the following alternative:

```
class Load{
    public function view($page){
       include($page);
    }
}

class Base{
    private $load; //note the private modifier
    function __construct(){
        $this->load = new Load();
    }

    public function view($page){
        $this->load->view($page);
    }
}
```

This way I just need to know that `Base` has a method `view($page)` and i don't have to know anymore what `Load` does at all.

If in the future you want to change the Load class you can do it under the hood without the `Base` users ever noticing it, if you do it right:

Suppose you define a class:

```
class BetterLoad {
    private function foo(){
         //do something awesome
    }

    private function advancedView($page){
         include($page);
         $this->foo();
    }
}
```

and you want to incorporate this inside `Base` instead of the old Load.

```
class Base{
    private $adv_load; //note the private modifier
    function __construct(){
        $this->adv_load = new BetterLoad();
    }

    public function view($page){
        $this->adv_load->advancedView($page);
    }
}
```

That's it. You won't need to change anything else in your code. Just go on using the old `$base_obj->view($page)` and you're good to go, without even noticing the change.